# Hello,team! Looking for a simple way to find out, how many columns return format-table commandlet

Tags: powershell, formattable

I have function to proxying format-table output.
Sometimes iam parsing huge object with a great numbers of properties.

Iam plan to add parameter [switch] $SplitLongTables, to split table into numbers of sub tables by properties.

Main idea is, that each table not wider than console size.
I see members properties on format-table object. But cant use it.

Comment: I'd consider using a gridview instead. ;-)

Comment: Sounds like this would be much easier if you skipped `Format-Table` entirely?

Comment: Its console script. I cant use out-grid.